# Spatial and Non-spatial Domain

Tags: grammar, linguistics

> **I go home.**

Why is **home** a *preposition* in this example?

Comment: Why do you think it’s a preposition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the word 'home" never an adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/511146/is-the-word-home-never-an-adverb) You don't provide much information on why you think it's a preposition.

Comment: Apparently some dictionaries (e.g. Wiktionary) classify this usage as a preposition, but others don't. For example, Merriam-Webster classifies this usage as an adverb.

Comment: Also the title on this question is very confusing. Spatial and non spatial domain? It sounds like some kind of mathematical concept, but in fact you're just asking about how to use the word "home".

Comment: It's a preposition, not an adverb, because in a clause the latter generally occur in adjunct rather than complement function. Further, "home" could be replaced with, for example, the PPs "to my place of residence" / "to where I reside".